# How to create and show partial views using Xcode storyboard / interface builder for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm brushing up on my Xcode visual layout skills. I would like to create a series of views that are just the centre section of the overall view. Then move them in / out horizontally based on user responses.

So in the image below View 1 is the default view and the header & footer images are visible top and bottom. When the user perfoms an action, view 2 should move in from right replacing (or over the top of) View 1 but not obscuring or removing the Header & Footer images.

In code this is relatively straightforward but I am wondering how can I create these 'partial' views using storyboards?

Thanks!

[image: views]

Comment: Try using container view in storyboard

Comment: you wd better avoid storyboard. it sucks! you can just create these view separately. like (  `myView1.swift` and  `myView1.xib` ) and then you can call that view from inside your controller and show it as you like